# Add "http" to embedded Vimeo iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm using Vimeo's [oEmbed API](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed) to replace the thumbnail with embedded video on click.

The `src` attribute in the embedded `<iframe>` HTML doesn't contain "http". instead, it's rendered as `src="//player.vimeo.com/video/00000000"`. This prevents the video from loading.

Do I have to update this URL automatically? After going through the Vimeo FAQ, it seems like this could be an issue with HTTP / HTTPS.

How can I work around this?

Comment: That is a protocol-less url, and should work fine.  It allows the video to load properly whether your site is `http` or `https`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var src= ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') +'//player.vimeo.com/video/00000000'
```